# Laughlin gauge argument, integer quantum hall and periodic boundary conditions

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, topology, gauge-invariance, quantum-hall-effect

In every treatment I have seen of the Laughlin gauge argument, it is suggested that as a flux quantum, $\Phi_0 = h/e$, threads through the cylinder or ribbon, that one unit of charge is pumped from one edge to the other per Landau level.

My question is: Why does the flux threaded have to be in integer units of $\Phi_0$?

In the particle-on-a-ring problem, the flux inserted can be a non-integral value. Why is it different in the Laughlin argument? (In Laughlin's original paper, he deems a gauge transformation to be *illegal* unless it is in units of $\Phi_0$, but I do not necessarily see why this is the case. See here: https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.23.5632)

In a superconducting ring, one has flux quantization, but I would not expect such a phenomenon with single-particle states in the quantum Hall effect.

Comment: This is because when the inserted flux is a multiple of $\Phi_0$, this flux can be gauged away by performing a gauge transformation, and the Hamitlonian is therefore gauge-equivalent to the one without flux, with identical energy levels and eigenstates. Then we can talk about how many charges are pumped in this cyclic process.

Comment: Why do we require in this problem that the flux can be "gauged away"? As I mentioned in the question, in the particle-on-a-ring problem, any flux can be inserted. Why is it different here?

Comment: Sure, any flux can be inserted. But the purpose of this argument is to compare what happens before and after the flux insertion. If the flux can not be gauged away, then the system is completely different, with different energy levels, different wavefunctions, etc, and there is no way to meaningfully talk about charge pumping. This is actually analogous to the situation one encounters in the definition Berry phase (and it goes beyond an analogy, but I will not elaborate on this now).

Comment: I guess this is ultimately my question -- why do we only consider the case where the system is mapped back to itself? When you say that "there is no way to meaningfully talk about charge pumping", are you saying that this argument works because charges are discrete and one can only transfer an integer number of charges from one edge to the other? Is this is ultimate reason why only flux quanta can be inserted?

Comment: Again you can insert any flux you want, nothing is wrong. Let me elaborate a bit more on the reason for having a cyclic process: For integer quantum Hall, it is helpful to think about single-particle Landau levels. The flux insertion is supposed to be adiabatic, so there are no transitions of electrons to other levels. All that happen is that the electrons are "carried" by the Landau levels, which are "flowing" from one side to another during the process (I'm skipping a lot of details here). However, in the end, the levels must return to their initial positions. (continue in the next comment)

Comment: So the only thing that can happen is that there are some number of levels from the two edges crossing the Fermi level. If $n$ levels cross on one edge of the annulus, then exactly $n$ levels cross on the other side in the opposite direction. And by adiabaticity, this number is the number of charges pumped, which is an integer.

Comment: The charge pumping I mentioned is known as "Thouless pump". In one sentence, the reason to have flux quanta inserted is to make the whole process a Thouless pump, and Thouless showed that charge transport is quantized. The paper by Thouless and Niu is actually quite readable: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0305-4470/17/12/016/pdf

Comment: Thanks so much -- this is really helpful. I think you've answered my question, even though it was only in the  comments!

Comment: No problem! I might convert this to an actual answer at some point.